# I don't want to repeat code selenium in Java

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I don't want to repeat following code in each test case using TestNG. Please give a suggestion.
I kept `prop` and `fis` as the global variables, initialized them in `openBrowser()`, then used in other methods, but I get `NullPointerExeption` on a prop. If I add the lines below, then I don't get it.

I just want to load the property file once and re-use it.

```
Properties prop = new Properties();
FileInputStream fis = new
FileInputStream("C:\\Users\\xxxxx\\URL.properties");
prop.load(fis);
```

Code:

```
public class CallUrl {  
WebDriver driver;
Properties prop ;
FileInputStream fis;        
@BeforeTest
public void openBrowser() throws IOException
{
     Properties prop = new Properties();
     FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream("C:\\Users\\xxxx\\URL.properties");
     prop.load(fis);             System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","C:\\Users\\xxxx\\chromedriver.exe");
        String browserType = prop.getProperty("Browser");       
    if ( browserType.equals("Chrome"))
        {             System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","C:\\Users\\Ashish\\Documents\\Selenium\\drivers\\chromedriver_win32\\chromedriver.exe");
          driver = new ChromeDriver(options);   
        }
    else if(browserType.equals("FireFox"))
    {
        driver = new FirefoxDriver();
    }         
}

@Test
public void openURL() throws IOException
{   
    Properties prop = new Properties();
    FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream("C:\\Users\\xxxxx\\URL.properties");
    prop.load(fis); 
        driver.get(prop.getProperty("URL"));
        WebDriverWait myDynamicElement = new WebDriverWait(driver,30);          myDynamicElement.until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//input[@name='userName']")));
}

@Test(dependsOnMethods={"openURL"})
public void loginToTours () throws InterruptedException, IOException
{
    Properties prop = new Properties();
    FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream("C:\\Users\\xxxxx\\URL.properties");
    prop.load(fis);         driver.findElement(By.name("userName")).sendKeys(prop.getProperty("login"));        driver.findElement(By.name("password")).sendKeys(prop.getProperty("password"));
    driver.findElement(By.name("login")).click();       
}       
}
```

Comment: Abstract base class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can move them to `BeforeClass` which will execute only once before all the tests of the class. I personally do not like the idea of tests initiating the browsers, directly dealing with page elements. I would suggest you implement page object model - check [here](http://www.testautomationguru.com/arquillian-graphene-page-fragments/)

```
public class CallUrl {
 WebDriver driver;
 Properties prop;

 @BeforeClass
 public void loadProps(){
    prop = new Properties();
    FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream("C:\\Users\\xxxx\\URL.properties");
    prop.load(fis);
 }


 @BeforeTest
 public void openBrowser() throws IOException {
  System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:\\Users\\xxxx\\chromedriver.exe");
  String browserType = prop.getProperty("Browser");
  if (browserType.equals("Chrome")) {
   System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:\\Users\\Ashish\\Documents\\Selenium\\drivers\\chromedriver_win32\\chromedriver.exe");
   driver = new ChromeDriver(options);
  } else if (browserType.equals("FireFox")) {
   driver = new FirefoxDriver();
  }
 }

 @Test
 public void openURL() throws IOException {
  driver.get(prop.getProperty("URL"));
  WebDriverWait myDynamicElement = new WebDriverWait(driver, 30);
  myDynamicElement.until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//input[@name='userName']")));
 }

 @Test(dependsOnMethods = {
  "openURL"
 })
 public void loginToTours() throws InterruptedException, IOException {
  driver.findElement(By.name("userName")).sendKeys(prop.getProperty("login"));
  driver.findElement(By.name("password")).sendKeys(prop.getProperty("password"));
  driver.findElement(By.name("login")).click();
 }
}
```

Comment: .It worked but when I used BeforeTest method , I got nullpointerException and not for BeforeClass..why? Whats different about BeforeClass ??

Comment: Problem was with `Properties prop = new Properties();` - you create a local variable for the method which is not available for other methods.